# Jqgrid filtering not working for complete word and data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

Filtering of jqgrid client side. The Problems iam facing are:

1. Filtering is working only in two columns(Project Ref and Project name in the below code) and only or some part of the word.
2. Filtering is not working for the data which is coming another table. I am using two datatables for retrieving of data. Works only for the direct table doesnt work for referenced table data.
3. Can I have theesearch without Loadonce true.Because it is not allowing to reload

I have tried with the following below code let me know where iam doing wrong

In view:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.button").button();
    var url = '@Url.Action("ListAllProjects")' + '?s_partId=' + '@ViewBag.PartId';
    var colNames = ['<input type="checkbox" onclick="CheckAll(this.checked,\'chkOF_\',event);" name="checkall">',
        'Status',
        'Project Ref',
        'Project Name',
        'Customer',
        'CreatedBy',
        'Creation Date',
        'Last Modified',
        'LastModifiedDate',
        'Edit'];
    var colModel = [
        { name: 'ProjectId', index: 'ProjectId', align: 'left', formatter: checkFormatter, width: 20, search: true },
        { name: 'ProjectStatusId', index: 'ProjectStatusId', edittype: 'image', align: 'left', width: 70, formatter: imageFormatter, search: true },
        { name: 'ProjectReference', index: 'ProjectReference', align: 'left', width: 100, formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { "baseLinkUrl": "/Ordernew/Home" }, search: true },
        { name: 'ProjectName', index: 'ProjectName', align: 'left', width: 150, formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { "baseLinkUrl": "/Ordernew/Home" }, search: true },
        { name: 'CustomerName', index: 'CustomerName', align: 'left', width: 150, search: true },
        { name: 'CreatedBy', index: 'CreatedBy', align: 'left', width: 150, search: true },
        { name: 'CreationDate', index: 'CreationDate', align: 'left', width: 100, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'd-M-y h:m A' }, search: true },
        { name: 'LastModifiedBy', index: 'LastModifiedBy', align: 'left', width: 100, search: true },
        { name: 'LastModifiedDate', index: 'LastModifiedDate', align: 'left', width: 100, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'd-M-y h:m A' }, search: true },
        { name: 'StatusId', index: 'ProjectStatusId', formatter: myCustomFormatter, align: 'left', width: 70, search: true },
    ];
    var sortname = 'ProjectStatusId';
    var sortorder = 'desc';     
    SetGrid('#jqgprojectnew', '', url, colNames, colModel, sortname, sortorder, -1,'#count',true);

    $("#jqgprojectnew").jqGrid('filterToolbar',
            {
                stringResult: true,
                searchOnEnter: false,
                defaultSearch: "cn"
            });




});
```

And setting the grid like this which is common for all the grids. But i need search only for the above grid:

```
function SetGrid(v_gridCtrl,v_pagingCtrl, v_url, v_colNames, v_colModel, v_sortname, v_sortorder, v_Pagesize,Count,Loadonce) {

if (v_Pagesize == undefined)
    v_Pagesize = 100;

$(v_gridCtrl).jqGrid({
    //url from wich data should be requested
    autowidth: true,
    url: v_url,
    //type of data
    datatype: 'json',
    //url access method type
    mtype: 'POST',
    //columns names
    colNames: v_colNames,
    //columns model
    colModel: v_colModel,
    //pager for grid
    pager: $(v_pagingCtrl),
    //enable dynamic scrolling
    //scroll: true,
    //enable npage request parameter
    prmNames: { npage: 'npage' },
    //number of rows per page
    rowNum: v_Pagesize,
    rowList: [10, 30, 60, 90, 100, 150, -1],
    loadComplete: function () {
        $("option[value=-1]").text('All');
        $(Count).html($(v_gridCtrl).getGridParam("reccount"));
    },
    loadonce:Loadonce,
    //initial sorting column
    sortname: v_sortname,
    //initial sorting direction
    sortorder: v_sortorder,
    //we want to display total records count
    viewrecords: true,
    //grid height
    height: 400,//'100%',
    //width: '100%',
    scrollOffset: 0,
    shrinkToFit: true,


});
```

}

Code for Adding record :

```
  public bool AddUpdateOrderField(ProjectViewModelNew obj)
    {



                var rec = new Project
                              {
                                  ProjectID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                  ProjectDetail = obj.ProjectDetail,
                                  CustomerId =obj.Id,
                                  ProjectName = obj.ProjectName,
                                  CreatedBy = new UserManager().Userid(),
                                  CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                                  LastModifiedBy = new UserManager().Userid(),
                                  ProjectRef = obj.ProjectRef,

                                  ProjectStatusId = obj.ProjectStatusId,
                                  LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
                                  OwnerID = new Guid("BEBB9E61-1F06-4762-80D8-5E4D554EAEB5")

                              };
                _context.Projects.AddObject(rec);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                return true;

    }
```

Comment: If you are using local search, you should set loadonce =true and it doesn't matter, from how many tables your data is fetched to the jqgrid. If you want to make loadonce=false, then youshould post search criteria to server and perform a database search.

Comment: the problem with the loadonce=true. i have to refresh my grids often and after setting load once true the data in the grid is missing after reload

Comment: Try removing   `stringResult: true,` to solve your first issue

Comment: Yeah first issue is solved and the remaining

Comment: You mean your pblms are solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using local search, you should set `loadonce =true` and it doesn't matter, from how many tables your data is fetched to the jqgrid. If you want to make `loadonce=false,` then you should post search criteria to server and perform a database search.

And try removing `stringResult: true,` to solve your first issue

To make the search case insensitive, add this to jqgrid properties:

ie ;

```
    $(v_gridCtrl).jqGrid({
    //url from wich data should be requested
    autowidth: true,
.....
 ignoreCase:true,
...}
```

And to reload the grid, try the following code:

$( v_gridCtrl ).trigger( 'reloadGrid', [{ page: 1}] );

Comment: 2. After adding a record and reloading the grid is not displaying all the data as load once is set true

Comment: You question doesn't say anything about adding a new record.

Comment: 3rd point is related to that it is not displaying after reload.Any way it was mistake and marked your answer as answered. About case sensitive please

Comment: See my modified answer. ignorCase:true

Comment: And, how are you adding the new record to jqgrid? Can you include the code?

Comment: Yeah fine thanks slacker..reload grid is not working properly function ReloadGridProject(v_gridCtrl, urlvalue, pageIndex) {
    alert(v_gridCtrl);
        $(v_gridCtrl).setGridParam({ datatype: 'json', page: 1 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
   
  
}

Comment: What do you mean by reloadgrid not working? New rows are not loaded or no rows at all?

Comment: New rows are not relaoding

Comment: How did you save the new rows? locally or to the database? Can you post the code you used to save the new rows?

Comment: I save the new records to the database

Comment: Then you must set loadonce to false .

Comment: In that case you will have to post the search parameters to action method and perform a database search